# Exception Handling in Netflix Feign

Tags: java, netflix-feign

I am using Netflix Feign to call HTTP Request as below -

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json; Accept: application/json")
public interface EmployeeClient {

  @RequestLine("POST")
  @Headers("client-id: TEST")   
  EmployeeResponse employee(EmployeeRequest employeeRequest);
}
```

How can I handle Exceptions here if service throw an error or service is not reachable or down. How can I use ErrorDecoder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using `Netflix Feign` standalone not with spring boot.

You can easily integrate a custom ErrorDecoder while building Feign client.

```
Feign.builder().errorDecoder(new MyCustomErrorDecoder())
                 .target(MyApi.class, "https://api.hostname.com");
```

For more details please look into official documentation [here](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#error-handling)